# What does INT(1) stand for in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

`INT(1)` - I know, 1 does not mean 1 digit, it represents client output display format only.

but what does this signify

i have declared `YEAR` as `int(1)`, I still see all 4 bytes. please tell me what does `INT(1)` means ?

```sql
SELECT * FROM TEST_USERDB;
```

```
+----+--------+------+
| ID | NAME   | YEAR |
+----+--------+------+
|  1 | abcccc | 2012 |
|  2 | stack  |   99 |
+----+--------+------+
```

Comment: http://alexander.kirk.at/2007/08/24/what-does-size-in-intsize-of-mysql-mean/ does a good job of explaining it

Comment: BTW: MySQL has a [datatype `YEAR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/year.html)…

Comment: It's up to client application how to interpret 'display width' passed with metadata. The parameter does not constraint value of the column

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> An `unsigned int` has the max value of `4294967295` no matter if its
>   `INT(1)` or `int(10)` and will use 4 bytes of data.
>
> So, what does the number in the brackets mean?  It pretty much comes
>   down to display, its called the display-width.  The display width is a
>   number from 1 to 255. You can set the display width if you want all of
>   your integer values to “appear”.  If you enable zerofill on the row,
>   the field will have a default value of 0 for `int(1)` and `0000000000` for
>   `int(10)`.

[Read more](http://www.bajb.net/2008/10/mysql-int1-or-int10/)

Comment: Do you mean 1 in int(1) only make sense if i use autofill ??

Comment: Of course, it's only used, if you use `UNSIGNED` and `ZEROFILL` with an *integer type*. I could find it's mentioned [here](http://everythingmysql.ning.com/profiles/blogs/data-type-confusion-what-is-an).