# MySQL minimum CHAR storage for constant strings

Tags: mysql

I have a very simple table that just has two values: `id` and `type`. The longest string in `type` is 11 characters ("Directorate").

Should I be using `CHAR(11)` or `CHAR(12)` in the `CREATE` command? Does MySQL actually store 12 bytes for `CHAR(11)` where the 12th byte is the NULL character or is this not relevant to storage?

**Edit**: As Joni pointed out, this does not use 11 or 12 bytes, it uses 33 or 36 bytes because I am storing as utf-8. However, my question is if I should be using 11 or 12 in `CHAR(x)`

Comment: [See](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11563830/1391249).

Comment: @Tiny, that link is about `INT`...

Comment: How many types are there?  If there are only a limited number of known types, you might actually get better storage in enum.

Comment: There are only 7 entries in the whole table. The benefit of storage is not really important, I asked the question because I wanted to know if I needed to think about NULL termination in MySQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The storage required for CHAR(M) is

> M × w bytes, 0 <= M <= 255, where w is the number of bytes required for the maximum-length character in the character set.

(Source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/storage-requirements.html)

That is, if you use `ascii` or some other single byte encoding, `CHAR(M)` is stored in M bytes. If you use `utf8` it is stored in 3*M bytes.

Comment: In my case I have utf-8, M = 11, and w = 3 so it uses 33 bytes. What I am asking is if M really should be 11 or 12 if the largest string is 11 characters.

Comment: Use CHAR(11) to store 11 characters. Then again, if these are constant strings that won't change you could use an ENUM instead.